# Tool that improves compression by uncompressing inner archives

Tags: linux, compression, gzip, tar, archive

There was a compression tool that uncompressed the inner gz/bz2/xz/etc files before storing them in a tar format and archiving them, and I don't remember its name. I'm creating archives that contain very similar rpm/deb/tgz packages, and only applying compression at the end will probably improve compression ratio significantly.

From what I remember, the tool also stored a metadata file that recorded what compression options were used, in order to reproduce identical zipped files during decompression.

Comment: I thought about posting this to SuperUser instead, but none of the tags I used here are available there. And ServerFault is for server administration, which doesn't sound right either.

Answer (score 0):

Found it: https://github.com/schnaader/precomp-cpp

It's not clear yet whether it only does recompressing of a given archive, or it also accepts a list of input files/dirs (some of which may already be compressed), like tar does.

Comment: Multiple file support is not supported ([yet](https://github.com/schnaader/precomp-cpp/issues/104)), so at the moment, you'll have to work around this by using tar first and applying precomp to the .tar file afterwards.

Comment: I went with the tar approach but I couldn't get it to shrink rpm's, maybe due to the lzma compression used: https://mirror.yandex.ru/fedora/linux/releases/33/